# Drawing objects and erasing them

Tags: java, swing, draw

I have this program that draw a circle with every click, my problem is that it erase the circle when I click somewhere else. How can I make the program keep  the circle without erasing the previous one ? I also want to create a button that erase all circles, is there is a method that erase everything ?

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class CircleObj extends JPanel {
    private int rColor;
    private int gColor;
    private int bColor;
    private int radius;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int xStart;
    private int yStart;
    ArrayList <Circle> xxx ;

    public CircleObj () {
    xxx =  new ArrayList<Circle>();

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e) {

        xStart = e.getX();
        yStart = e.getY();
        rColor = rand.nextInt(256);
        gColor = rand.nextInt(256);
        bColor = rand.nextInt(256);
        radius = rand.nextInt(100);
        xxx.add(new Circle(xStart, yStart,rColor, gColor, bColor, radius));
        System.out.println(xxx);
        repaint();
        }
    }); // end addMouseListener

    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(rColor, gColor, bColor));
    g.fillOval(xStart, yStart, radius, radius);

    }

     class Circle {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int rad;
        private int rcol;
        private int gcol;
        private int bcol;

        public Circle (int xValue, int yValue,int redValue, int greenValue, int blueValue, int radValue) {

            x = xValue;
            y = yValue;
            rad = radValue;
            rcol = redValue;
            gcol = greenValue;
            bcol = blueValue;
            }


        public String toString (){

        return String.format("X value is: " + x + "\nY value is: " + y + "\nRadius value is: " +rad +
                   "\nRed value is: "+ rcol+ "\nGreen value is: "+ gcol + "\nBlue value is: "+bcol+ "\n\n");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Another way to do it is draw each new element to a `BufferedImage` displayed in a `JLabel`.  Each time the image is updated, repaint the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a list of circles, that look unused to me - whenever you click you add a circle but you only draw a circle where you click...

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //g.setColor(new Color(rColor, gColor, bColor));
    //g.fillOval(xStart, yStart, radius, radius);
    for (Circle circle: xxx){
        g.setColor(new Color(circle.rcol, circle.gcol, circle.bcol));
        g.fillOval(circle.x, circle.y, circle.rad, circle.rad);
    }
}
```

use this approach to add circles to your screen - if you want to remove them, make a button or any other event and call `xxx.clear()` which cleans the list (don't forget to `repaint()` after clearing the list...